# How to execute a function to update a json source

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, leaflet

I have a Leaflet map that show some weather data from a Json source. I have already a function that update the data every x minutes by a setInterval function.

```
    setTimeout(function () {
        refreshId = setInterval(function () {

            $.ajax({
                method: 'get',
                dataType: 'text',
                url: 'myURLfile.json',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data) {
                        markers = [];
                        var withoutMarkers = data.slice(10);
                        markers = JSON.parse(withoutMarkers);
                        //console.log(markers);

                        replaceMarkers(currentFactor);

                    }
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.error('there is not date for today.', err)
                }
            })
        }, 300000);
    },10000)

}
```

What I would to do now is assign this funtion to a button to execute the refresh fuction manually. 
Something like

```
        L.easyButton( 'fas fa-cloud-sun-rain', function(){
            myfunction()
        }, 'Refresh', {
            position: 'topright'
        })
```

But I don't understand what I have to call exactely to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factor your fetch code out of `setInterval` and use your newly made function both in `setInterval` and your button definition.

Something like

```
function fetchData() {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'get',
        dataType: 'text',
        url: 'myURLfile.json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                markers = [];
                var withoutMarkers = data.slice(10);
                markers = JSON.parse(withoutMarkers);
                //console.log(markers);

                replaceMarkers(currentFactor);

            }
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.error('there is not date for today.', err)
        }
    });
}

// setup your interval
setInterval(fetchData, 300000);

// setup your button
L.easyButton( 'fas fa-cloud-sun-rain', fetchData, 'Condizioni', {
    position: 'topright'
})
```